# Currency converter without using if else

Tags: python, tkinter, data-structures

I am writing a currency converter program using if-else statements on tkinter. I have written it for only six of the currencies and it's taking too long.

What if I want to write for hundreds of currencies? Do I use if-else on that also? Is there a more efficient way to program a currency converter without using If-Else statements?

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk


class CurrencyConverter(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.title('Currency Converter')
        self.geometry('500x300')

        self.currencies_list = ['United States Dollar', 'Pound Sterling', 'Euro', 'Pakistani Rupee', 'Swiss Franc',
                                'Japanese Yen']
        self.usd_to_other_list = [1, 0.72, 0.85, 153.50, 0.94, 110.70]
        self.ps_to_other_list = [1.38, 1, 1.18, 212.15, 1.3, 153]
        self.euro_to_other_list = [1.18, 0.85, 1, 180.55, 1.11, 130.19]
        self.pkr_to_other_list = [0.0065, 0.0047, 0.0055, 1, 0.0061, 0.72]
        self.sf_to_other_list = [1.06, 0.77, 0.9, 162.79, 1, 117.46]
        self.jy_to_other_list = [0.009, 0.0065, 0.0077, 1.39, 0.0085, 1]

        self.from_currency = tk.StringVar()
        self.to_currency = tk.StringVar()
        self.from_entry_variable = tk.IntVar()
        self.to_entry_variable = tk.IntVar()

        self.from_entry = ttk.Entry(
            self,
            textvariable=self.from_entry_variable,
            width=40
        )
        self.from_combobox = ttk.Combobox(
            self,
            textvariable=self.from_currency,
            values=tuple(self.currencies_list),
            state='readonly'
        )
        self.from_combobox.set(self.currencies_list[0])

        self.to_entry = ttk.Entry(
            self,
            textvariable=self.to_entry_variable,
            width=40,
            state='readonly'
        )
        self.to_combobox = ttk.Combobox(
            self,
            textvariable=self.to_currency,
            values=tuple(self.currencies_list),
            state='readonly'
        )
        self.to_combobox.set(self.currencies_list[4])

        self.from_entry.pack()
        self.from_combobox.pack()
        self.to_entry.pack()
        self.to_combobox.pack()

        self.from_entry.bind('<KeyPress>', self.currency_converter)
        self.from_entry.bind('<KeyRelease>', self.currency_converter)

    def currency_converter(self, event):
        try:
            if self.from_currency.get() == 'United States Dollar':

                if self.to_currency.get() == 'United States Dollar':
                    converted = int(self.from_entry_variable.get()) * self.usd_to_other_list[0]
                    self.to_entry_variable.set(value=f'{converted}')

                elif self.to_currency.get() == 'Pound Sterling':
                    converted = int(self.from_entry_variable.get()) * self.usd_to_other_list[1]
                    self.to_entry_variable.set(value=f'{converted}')

                elif self.to_currency.get() == 'Euro':
                    converted = int(self.from_entry_variable.get()) * self.usd_to_other_list[2]
                    self.to_entry_variable.set(value=f'{converted}')

                elif self.to_currency.get() == 'Pakistani Rupee':
                    converted = int(self.from_entry_variable.get()) * self.usd_to_other_list[3]
                    self.to_entry_variable.set(value=f'{converted}')

                elif self.to_currency.get() == 'Swiss Franc':
                    converted = int(self.from_entry_variable.get()) * self.usd_to_other_list[4]
                    self.to_entry_variable.set(value=f'{converted}')

                elif self.to_currency.get() == 'Japanese Yen':
                    converted = int(self.from_entry_variable.get()) * self.usd_to_other_list[5]
                    self.to_entry_variable.set(value=f'{converted}')

            elif self.from_currency.get() == 'Pound Sterling':

                if self.to_currency.get() == 'United States Dollar':
                    converted = int(self.from_entry_variable.get()) * self.ps_to_other_list[0]
                    self.to_entry_variable.set(value=f'{converted}')

                elif self.to_currency.get() == 'Pound Sterling':
                    converted = int(self.from_entry_variable.get()) * self.ps_to_other_list[1]
                    self.to_entry_variable.set(value=f'{converted}')

                elif self.to_currency.get() == 'Euro':
                    converted = int(self.from_entry_variable.get()) * self.ps_to_other_list[2]
                    self.to_entry_variable.set(value=f'{converted}')

                elif self.to_currency.get() == 'Pakistani Rupee':
                    converted = int(self.from_entry_variable.get()) * self.ps_to_other_list[3]
                    self.to_entry_variable.set(value=f'{converted}')

                elif self.to_currency.get() == 'Swiss Franc':
                    converted = int(self.from_entry_variable.get()) * self.ps_to_other_list[4]
                    self.to_entry_variable.set(value=f'{converted}')

                elif self.to_currency.get() == 'Japanese Yen':
                    converted = int(self.from_entry_variable.get()) * self.ps_to_other_list[5]
                    self.to_entry_variable.set(value=f'{converted}')

            elif self.from_currency.get() == 'Euro':

                if self.to_currency.get() == 'United States Dollar':
                    converted = int(self.from_entry_variable.get()) * self.euro_to_other_list[0]
                    self.to_entry_variable.set(value=f'{converted}')

                elif self.to_currency.get() == 'Pound Sterling':
                    converted = int(self.from_entry_variable.get()) * self.euro_to_other_list[1]
                    self.to_entry_variable.set(value=f'{converted}')

                elif self.to_currency.get() == 'Euro':
                    converted = int(self.from_entry_variable.get()) * self.euro_to_other_list[2]
                    self.to_entry_variable.set(value=f'{converted}')

                elif self.to_currency.get() == 'Pakistani Rupee':
                    converted = int(self.from_entry_variable.get()) * self.euro_to_other_list[3]
                    self.to_entry_variable.set(value=f'{converted}')

                elif self.to_currency.get() == 'Swiss Franc':
                    converted = int(self.from_entry_variable.get()) * self.euro_to_other_list[4]
                    self.to_entry_variable.set(value=f'{converted}')

                elif self.to_currency.get() == 'Japanese Yen':
                    converted = int(self.from_entry_variable.get()) * self.euro_to_other_list[5]
                    self.to_entry_variable.set(value=f'{converted}')

            elif self.from_currency.get() == 'Pakistani Rupee':

                if self.to_currency.get() == 'United States Dollar':
                    converted = int(self.from_entry_variable.get()) * self.pkr_to_other_list[0]
                    self.to_entry_variable.set(value=f'{converted}')

                elif self.to_currency.get() == 'Pound Sterling':
                    converted = int(self.from_entry_variable.get()) * self.pkr_to_other_list[1]
                    self.to_entry_variable.set(value=f'{converted}')

                elif self.to_currency.get() == 'Euro':
                    converted = int(self.from_entry_variable.get()) * self.pkr_to_other_list[2]
                    self.to_entry_variable.set(value=f'{converted}')

                elif self.to_currency.get() == 'Pakistani Rupee':
                    converted = int(self.from_entry_variable.get()) * self.pkr_to_other_list[3]
                    self.to_entry_variable.set(value=f'{converted}')

                elif self.to_currency.get() == 'Swiss Franc':
                    converted = int(self.from_entry_variable.get()) * self.pkr_to_other_list[4]
                    self.to_entry_variable.set(value=f'{converted}')

                elif self.to_currency.get() == 'Japanese Yen':
                    converted = int(self.from_entry_variable.get()) * self.pkr_to_other_list[5]
                    self.to_entry_variable.set(value=f'{converted}')

            elif self.from_currency.get() == 'Swiss Franc':

                if self.to_currency.get() == 'United States Dollar':
                    converted = int(self.from_entry_variable.get()) * self.sf_to_other_list[0]
                    self.to_entry_variable.set(value=f'{converted}')

                elif self.to_currency.get() == 'Pound Sterling':
                    converted = int(self.from_entry_variable.get()) * self.sf_to_other_list[1]
                    self.to_entry_variable.set(value=f'{converted}')

                elif self.to_currency.get() == 'Euro':
                    converted = int(self.from_entry_variable.get()) * self.sf_to_other_list[2]
                    self.to_entry_variable.set(value=f'{converted}')

                elif self.to_currency.get() == 'Pakistani Rupee':
                    converted = int(self.from_entry_variable.get()) * self.sf_to_other_list[3]
                    self.to_entry_variable.set(value=f'{converted}')

                elif self.to_currency.get() == 'Swiss Franc':
                    converted = int(self.from_entry_variable.get()) * self.sf_to_other_list[4]
                    self.to_entry_variable.set(value=f'{converted}')

                elif self.to_currency.get() == 'Japanese Yen':
                    converted = int(self.from_entry_variable.get()) * self.sf_to_other_list[5]
                    self.to_entry_variable.set(value=f'{converted}')

            elif self.from_currency.get() == 'Japanese Yen':

                if self.to_currency.get() == 'United States Dollar':
                    converted = int(self.from_entry_variable.get()) * self.jy_to_other_list[0]
                    self.to_entry_variable.set(value=f'{converted}')

                elif self.to_currency.get() == 'Pound Sterling':
                    converted = int(self.from_entry_variable.get()) * self.jy_to_other_list[1]
                    self.to_entry_variable.set(value=f'{converted}')

                elif self.to_currency.get() == 'Euro':
                    converted = int(self.from_entry_variable.get()) * self.jy_to_other_list[2]
                    self.to_entry_variable.set(value=f'{converted}')

                elif self.to_currency.get() == 'Pakistani Rupee':
                    converted = int(self.from_entry_variable.get()) * self.jy_to_other_list[3]
                    self.to_entry_variable.set(value=f'{converted}')

                elif self.to_currency.get() == 'Swiss Franc':
                    converted = int(self.from_entry_variable.get()) * self.jy_to_other_list[4]
                    self.to_entry_variable.set(value=f'{converted}')

                elif self.to_currency.get() == 'Japanese Yen':
                    converted = int(self.from_entry_variable.get()) * self.jy_to_other_list[5]
                    self.to_entry_variable.set(value=f'{converted}')

        except TclError:
            pass


root = CurrencyConverter()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You could use a dictionary of functions.

Comment: One way to simplify is to have one *canonical currency*, to which all the others are compared. Then you don't need nested ifs, you do two conversions instead (input -> canonical -> output). Then you can have a dictionary mapping each currency to a single rate, its rate with the canonical currency (in the case of the canonical currency itself, that rate will be 1.0).

Comment: @jonrsharpe Do you have any references for that? Can you provide a piece of code so that I can understand or visualize it in a proper way?

Comment: I would suggest you spend a bit longer thinking about it and trying to apply it to your scenario, maybe start with just 2-3 currencies.

Comment: One way to check this would be to use a `for` loop. as previously mentioned it will be easier to just have one canonical currency and compare every other to it. so that would work like this. You have Your dictionary similar to this: `{'currency': 'Pound Sterling', 'value_to_dollar': 1.5}` and every time someone inputs a currency You loop over all Your dictionaries and search for when 'currency' matches user inputed currency and the use the value to calculate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to program a currency converter using a dictionary. The disadvantage of doing with if-else is that you'll go hectic typing hundreds of nested if-else in all the exchange rates.

### EXPLANATION

First, we need to have one canonical currency or base currency, to which all the other currencies are compared `(from_currency -> base_currency -> to_currency)`. Then you can have a dictionary mapping each currency to a single rate, its rate with the canonical currency (in the case of the canonical currency itself, that rate will be 1.0).

This answer's explanation was done by @jonrsharpe.

### ALGORITHM

Suppose I want to convert from `EUR` to `AED`.

Step # 1: Set a base/ canonical currency `(base currency: USD)`.

Step # 2: Convert `EUR` to `USD`.

Step # 3: Convert `USD` to `AED`.

### IMPLEMENTATION

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
from functools import partial


class CurrencyConverter(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.title('Currency Converter')
        self.geometry('500x300')

        # Base currency: USD
        self.rates = {
            'USD': 1,
            'EUR': 0.85,
            'AED': 3.67
        }

        self.currencies_list = ['USD', 'EUR', 'AED']

        self.from_currency = tk.StringVar()
        self.to_currency = tk.StringVar()
        self.from_entry_variable = tk.IntVar()
        self.to_entry_variable = tk.IntVar()

        self.from_entry = ttk.Entry(
            self,
            textvariable=self.from_entry_variable,
            width=40
        )
        self.from_combobox = ttk.Combobox(
            self,
            textvariable=self.from_currency,
            values=tuple(self.currencies_list),
            state='readonly'
        )
        self.from_combobox.set('USD')

        self.to_entry = ttk.Entry(
            self,
            textvariable=self.to_entry_variable,
            width=40,
            state='readonly'
        )
        self.to_combobox = ttk.Combobox(
            self,
            textvariable=self.to_currency,
            values=tuple(self.currencies_list),
            state='readonly'
        )
        self.to_combobox.set('EUR')

        self.button = ttk.Button(
            self,
            text='Convert',
            command=partial(self.currency_converter, self.from_entry_variable, self.from_currency, self.to_currency)
        )

        self.from_entry.pack()
        self.from_combobox.pack()
        self.to_entry.pack()
        self.to_combobox.pack()
        self.button.pack()
```

So, this is my `currency_converter()`. Here I am passing `*args` because I want to take three parameters  `amount`, `from_currency`, `to_currency`.

```
    def currency_converter(self, *args):
        _amount, _from_currency, _to_currency, = args
        amount, from_currency, to_currency = _amount.get(), _from_currency.get(), _to_currency.get()
        print(f'Amount: {amount}, From: {from_currency}, To: {to_currency}')

        if from_currency != 'USD':
            # Suppose I want to convert from EUR to AED.
            # Convert EUR to USD.
            usd = amount / self.rates[from_currency]
            # Convert USD to AED.
            amount = usd * self.rates[to_currency]
            print(amount)
        else:
            # In the case of the canonical currency itself, that rate will be 1.0
            amount = amount * self.rates[to_currency]
            print(amount)


root = CurrencyConverter()
root.mainloop()
```

Note: I have done it for only three currencies and my canonical currency is USD. If you want to add more currencies, just add them to `self.rates` with the rates of USD.

Answer (score 0):

Some function like this (I don't have Python compiler - minor errors may exist)?

```
 currencies_list = ['United States Dollar', 'Pound Sterling', 'Euro', 'Pakistani Rupee', 'Swiss Franc', 'Japanese Yen']
    usd_to_other_list = [1, 0.72, 0.85, 153.5, 0.94, 110.7]
    
    def GetParity(ValueToConvert, FromCurrency, ToCurrency):
        SourceIndex = currencies_list.Index(FromCurrency)
    
        DestIndex = currencies_list.Index(ToCurrency)
    
        SourceR = usd_to_other_list(SourceIndex)
    
        DestR = usd_to_other_list(DestIndex)
    
        Result = ValueToConvert * DestR / SourceR
        Return(Result)
```